# Question with nonempty bounds and sets

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Let $A$ and $B$ be nonempty sets of real numbers, bounded above and below. Prove that if $A\cap B$ is also nonempty, then $infB\leq supA$.

So my train of thought goes like this: I'm picturing that the elements in set B are generall greater than the elements in set A. Makes sense, since the lowest bound of B is less than or equal to the highest bound in A.

Now the problem I'm having here is using existing proofs to really put this altogether.  I understand that there is a completeness axiom that helps with the least upper bound, but the opposite is not really churning anything. Now the corollary to this would be that the subset of S that is bounded below has a greatest lower bound inf S. My other way of attempting this is to try turning on of these (as in A or B) the same but negative of the other. (I.E. B = -A) and applying this corollary.

Answer (score 1):

Since the sets are bounded above and below, $\inf B$ and $\sup A$ exist.

Let $x\in A\cap B$. Then $x$ is in $A$ and also in $B$. Thus
$$\inf B\le x \qquad\text{and} \qquad x\le \sup A.$$
The result follows.

Comment: Wow, could it really be that simple? Sometimes the simplest answer is really all you need

Comment: Yes, it is. If you want to be fancy, you can say that $\inf B\le x$ and $x\le \sup A$ implies $\inf B\le \sup A$ by the transitivity of $\le$. You may also want to explain why for example $\inf B\le x$. It follows from the definition of $\inf$ as being in particular a lower bound. But I think none of these elaborations is needed.